# C++ ввод и вывод в консоль

Tags: c++, классы, cin, std

Вопрос немного странный, но ответ найти не могу. Пишу класс массива, в нем есть перегруженные операторы ввода и вывода. Выглядят так:

```
template <class T, size_t rows, size_t cols>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const MatrixArray<T, rows, cols> &m) {
    for (size_t y = 0; y < rows; ++y) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < cols; ++x) {
            out << m(y, x) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return out;
}

template <class T, size_t rows, size_t cols>
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, MatrixArray<T, rows, cols> &m) {
    for (size_t y = 0; y < rows; ++y) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < cols; ++x) {
            in >> m(y, x);
        }
    }
    return in;
}
```

Затем в функции main я пишу такой код:

```
int main() {
    std::stringstream is{"-5 1\n0 10"};
    MatrixArray<int, 2, 2> matrix{};
    is >> matrix;

    std::stringstream os;
    os << matrix;
    std::cout << os.str();
}
```

Я вижу вывод:

```
-5 1 0 10
```

А хотел бы увидеть такой:

```
-5 1\n0 10\n
```

Подскажите, как можно это исправить?

Comment: `std::cout << '\n';` => `out << '\n';`

Comment: А вы точно используете тот код, который привели? Судя по нему в результате должен получится вывод, который вы хотите

Comment: @wololo помогло, спасибо! Проглядел